# How can I implement nearest neighbor interpolation in a JavaScript matrix operation?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

The following code uses [GPU.js](https://github.com/gpujs/gpu.js), a wrapper for WebGL that makes it easy to run matrix operations with WebGL by simply writing JS functions, I render an image on the canvas, but I want to resize it. I've [read about nearest neighbor interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest-neighbor_interpolation) but I'm confused on how to implement it. I've already set up the resize kernel, all that's left to be done is interpolation logic.

Notes:

- the current indexes are available within the kernel function as `this.thread.x`, `this.thread.y`, and `this.thread.z`, depending on the dimensions of the matrix your kernel is computing.
- You'll notice the canvas is sized weird. This is a "feature" of GPU.js related to WebGL texture handling (I think they're planning on ironing that out later).
- Edit: Made progress but not quite perfected: http://jsfiddle.net/0dusaytk/59/

```js
const canvas1 = document.createElement("canvas");
const context1 = canvas1.getContext("webgl2");
document.body.appendChild(canvas1);
const canvas2 = document.createElement("canvas");
const context2 = canvas2.getContext("2d");
const gpu = new GPU({
  canvas: canvas1,
  webGl: context1
});

const image = new Image();
image.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
image.src = "https://i.imgur.com/sl2J6jm.jpg";
image.onload = function() {
    const length = 4 * image.height * image.width;
  const gpuTexturize = gpu
    .createKernel(function(sprite) {
      return sprite[this.thread.x];
    })
    .setOutput([length])
    .setOutputToTexture(true);
  const gpuResize = gpu
    .createKernel(function(sprite, w, h) {
      return sprite[this.thread.x];
    })
    .setOutput([length])
    .setOutputToTexture(true);
  const gpuRender = gpu
    .createKernel(function(sprite, w, h) {
        var index = this.thread.x * 4 + (h - this.thread.y) * w * 4;
      var r = sprite[index];
      var g = sprite[index + 1];
      var b = sprite[index + 2];
      this.color(r / 255, g / 255, b / 255);
    })
    .setOutput([image.width, image.height])
    .setGraphical(true);
  canvas2.width = image.width;
  canvas2.height = image.height;
  context2.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
  const imgData = context2.getImageData(
    0,
    0,
    canvas2.width,
    canvas2.height
  );
  
  const texture = gpuTexturize(imgData.data);
  const resized = gpuResize(texture, 100, 100);
  gpuRender(resized, image.width, image.height);
};
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #3a4659;
}

canvas {
  background-color: #bcc8db;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gpu.js@latest/dist/gpu-browser.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, that Wikipedia page isn't really helpful. Afaik, nearest neighbour simply means you recalculate the position of your pixel, and take the colour of that pixel. E.g. if you're resizing to 70%, then a pixel at (50,40) will take the colour of the pixel at (round(50 / 0.7), round(40 / 0.7)) which is (71, 57).

Comment: I'm getting closer but not quite there: http://jsfiddle.net/0dusaytk/56/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added the second canvas with pixelated render in order to compare this implementation with the browser css default method.

Demo: https://codepen.io/rafaelcastrocouto/pen/pOaaEd

```js
const scale = 4;

// canvas1 will be handled by the gpu
const canvas1 = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas1.className = 'c1';
const context1 = canvas1.getContext("webgl2");
const gpu = new GPU({
  canvas: canvas1,
  webGl: context1
});
document.body.appendChild(canvas1);

// canvas2 will render the image
const canvas2 = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas2.className = 'c2';
const context2 = canvas2.getContext("2d");
document.body.appendChild(canvas2);
canvas2.style.transform = 'scale('+scale+')';

// load the image
const image = new Image();
image.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
image.src = "https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=20&txtpad=1&bg=000&txtclr=fff&txt=64x32&w=64&h=32";

image.onload = function() {
  // render image to canvas2
  canvas2.width = image.width;
  canvas2.height = image.height;
  context2.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
  // scale imageData
  const imgData = context2.getImageData(0,0,image.width,image.height);
  const gpuRender = gpu
    .createKernel(function(sprite) {
      var x = floor(this.thread.x/this.constants.s) * 4;
      var y = floor(this.constants.h - this.thread.y/this.constants.s) * 4 * this.constants.w;
      var index = x + y;
      var r = sprite[ index ]/255;
      var g = sprite[index+1]/255;
      var b = sprite[index+2]/255;
      var a = sprite[index+3]/255;
      this.color(r, g, b, a);
    },{
      constants: {
        w: image.width,
        h: image.height,
        s: scale
      }
    })
    .setOutput([image.width*scale, image.height*scale])
    .setGraphical(true);
  gpuRender(imgData.data);
};
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #3a4659;
}

canvas {
  background-color: #bcc8db;
  display: block;
  margin: 4em;
}
.c2 {
  image-rendering: pixelated;
  transform-origin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gpu.js@latest/dist/gpu-browser.min.js"></script>
```